# I am beginner in php and mysql I boss wanted to write the url like this in php?I ask stack team to give the possible link

Tags: php

I am beginner  in php and mysql my boss wanted to write the url like this in php? they are asking me to avoid showing the id primary key, php extension in url. for edit profile.

I don't want this type of url?

```
www.college.com/faculty_details.php?ID=21&Type=Self%20finance&Name=Commerce%20(AM)
```

I want this type of url:

```
http://www.matrimony.com/myprofile/

http://www.test.com/editprofile/
```

I only know plain php and mysql query.How to solve this using plain php. I expect give me the various possible answer?

Comment: take a look at [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: my .htaccess file is empty in my server what are first step i need to write in htccess file

Comment: .htaccess is not written in PHP, thats one thing to remember, further everything is explained in the URL I gave you.

Comment: HI I got that I don't understand RewriteCond,RewriteRule that's why i asked u what is the first step i need to write in .htaccess for example http://www.test.com/services.php or http://www.test.com/id=5 if you don't mind what is the first step i have write.once again i don't understand that

Answer (score 1):

Use rewrites in your .htaccess to rewrite the "ugly" urls to the nice ones, see: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049